# JMS Service not pushing XML files to Queue. Stops processing in between and needed to restart the service to push the files further

Tags: java, jms, heap-memory, jms-serializer, jms-queue

There is a directory named `/var/xyz/aa/clm/data/infiles/SenderJMS/CE/L3/` where number of XML files are stored after a process runs. These files contain data to be pushed to remote server through a JMS queue. The queue is configured at client's cloud server.

In `SenderJMS` service code we just use the JMS config credentials and queue name and then start pushing the files. Sometime the XML file list increases to 20K/30K, and in error log we get "OutOfMemoryError". Then the `SenderJMS` stops in the middle of processing. Then we are restarting the service to process, from where it stopped execution.

**Crdentials:**

```
Queue Name: VS.REVFDX.CL10.PUB.LAS.TCF.L3
jndi.environment.property.key.java.naming.provider.url=ldap://apptstldap.corp.<client_name>.com:888/ou=messaging,dc=corp,dc=<client_name>,dc=com
destination.jndiName=fxClientDestinationUID=D.REVFDX.DLRS.ToBeInvoiced

connection.factory.userid= XYZ_UID
connection.factory.password= PWD
```

**JNDI Configuration**

```java
@Bean(name = "jndiTemplate")
public JndiTemplate jndiTemplate() {
    JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
    Properties environment = new Properties();
    environment.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "jndi_environment_property_key_java_naming_factory_initial");
    environment.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "jndi_environment_property_key_java_naming_provider_url");
    jndiTemplate.setEnvironment(environment);
    return jndiTemplate;
}
```

**Queue Channel**

```java
@Bean(name="channel1")
public QueueChannel queueChannel() {
    return new QueueChannel();
}
```

**File Poller**

```java
@Bean(name="fileListPoller1")
public FileListPoller fileListPoller() {
    FileListPoller fp = new FileListPoller();
    fp.setDirectoryPath(file_inbound_dir);
    fp.setExcludes(excludes);
    return fp;
}
```

**Inbound Handler**

```java
@Bean(name="inboundHandler2",initMethod="initWS")
public InboundJMSHandlerWS inboundJMSHandlerWS() {
    InboundJMSHandlerWS inboundJMSHandlerWS = new InboundJMSHandlerWS();
    inboundJMSHandlerWS.setChannel(queueChannel());
    inboundJMSHandlerWS.setAddress(inbound_webservice_endpoint_address_4jms);
    return inboundJMSHandlerWS;
}
```

**Outbound Handler**

```java
@Bean(name="outboundJMSHandler1",initMethod="initThreadPool")
public OutboundJMSHandler outboundJMSHandler() {
    OutboundJMSHandler outboundJMSHandler = new OutboundJMSHandler();
    outboundJMSHandler.setChannel(queueChannel());
    outboundJMSHandler.setThreadPoolSize(outbound_jmshandler_thread_pool_size);
    outboundJMSHandler.setJndiTemplate(jndiTemplate());
    outboundJMSHandler.setJmsPoolSize(connection_pool_size);
    outboundJMSHandler.setConnectionFactoryJndiKey(connectionFactory_jndiName);
    outboundJMSHandler.setDestinationJndiKey(destination_jndiName);
    outboundJMSHandler.setInterfaceName(outbound_jms_interface_name);
    outboundJMSHandler.setTestLevel(outbound_jms_testLevel);
    outboundJMSHandler.setCnFactoryUID(connection_factory_userid);
    outboundJMSHandler.setCnFactoryPassword(connection_factory_password);
    outboundJMSHandler.setJmsMessageType(jms_message_type);
    return outboundJMSHandler;
}
```

**Error Details:**

```
Exception in thread "TIBCO EMS TCPLink Reader (Server-130801)" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Exception in thread "<ClientName>JMSStarvedConsumerTimer" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.
```

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=75M; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: MaxNewSize (512000k) is equal to or greater than the entire heap (512000k).  A new max generation size of 511936k will be used.
```

As in the log we got `OutOfMemoryError` we increased the heap size from 500MB to 1024MB(1GB), but that didn't resolve our issue. Like before, if the above issue come again, we need to restart the `SenderJMS` service again.

What could be the reason that the `SenderJMS` application is stopping in between? Do we need to check if the queue is full during file push?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know for sure why your application is running out of memory based on the information you've provided. You need to capture a heap dump when you hit the `OutOfMemoryError` and then analyze it to see what's consuming most of the memory.

To capture a heap dump when you hit the `OutOfMemoryError` you can use the `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` JVM parameter as described [here](https://%60https://www.baeldung.com/java-heap-dump-capture#automatically).

There are many tools you can use to analyze the heap dump (e.g. [JVisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/), [Eclipse MAT](https://eclipse.dev/mat/), etc.).